# Warning message about destroying data on all partitions for dual boot install with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, ubiquity

I was in the process of attempting to do a dual boot installation using the "Something Else" option on ubiquity when I ran into an error message. Despite selecting a partition for use that was NOT my primary Windows (C:) partition, it spat back at me the following warning:

"If you continue, the changes listed below will be written to the disks. Otherwise you will be able to make further changes manually. WARNING: This will destroy all data on any parttions you have removed as well as on the partitions that are going to be formatted.

The partition tables of the following devices are changed: SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda)

The following partitions are going to be formatted: partition #5 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) as ext4 partition #6 of SCSI1 (0,0,0 (sda) sd swap"

I'm concerned as to if my primary Windows partition will be destroyed due to the whole part about removed drives' data being destroyed, ostensibly in spite of not selecting them. Am I interpreting this warning correctly or should I proceed with the installation?

Hardware info:

Machine: MSI PE60-6QE

CPU: Intel i7 2.60 GHz Quad-Core

BIOS: American Megatrends E16J5IMS.106

Comment: You should try and learn a thing or two about a typical Ubuntu installation before actually attempting one. That and do your backups, of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
This will destroy all data on any parttions you have removed 
as well as on the partitions that are going to be formatted.
```

Only partitions you have marked for deletion and/or formatting will be destroyed. If you haven't marked your Windows partition(s) they will not be touched when installing Ubuntu.

That said, it is always a good idea to make a backup of all important data before doing major work like installing Ubuntu in dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

if  you are using a partition that do not contain any data ,then you don't need to worry about it.
to make sure everything goes right ,you may create a new partition from windows disk manager by shrinking some existing partition and leave it as unallocated .so it will be shown as "free space" while installing linux.

creating new partition is not necessary.
just make sure you are not formatting the windows partition.